# DateTime.TryParseExact doesnt return value in out parameter?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

The problem mentioned below has been solved and code has been changed to reflect changes.

I want to check the current date against a date stored in my MySQL database. to retrieve the current date I am using the nist time server which returns a date in the format MM-DD-YYYY and in my database I have values stored in the format "YYYY-MM-DD." What I want to do is checking if the date I pass is equal to the date in the database, then do something.

The code I am using is the following one:

```
// The code originally posted has been changed to reflect changes made and it is now working fine (problem solved) a big thank you to all those who replied.
DateTime currentDate = InternetTime();
//DD/MM/YYYY is returned here convert to YYYY/MM/DD
string currentDate = x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id AS oDates FROM open_dates WHERE dates=?currentDate",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?currentDate",currentDate);
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataTable dt = new DataTable("openDates");
da.Fill(dt);
```

the "dt" table remains empty because TryParseExact doesn't write anything to dateValue and so it remains "01-01-0001" or something like that. Where am I going wrong? It would be great if anyone could help me.
There is actually a workaround that I thought of; I could store strings in the database right away, and then check them, but that would be cheating; I want the date to work.
I tried searching for MySQL commands that could help me, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're ignoring the result of `DateTime.TryParseExact`. It will almost certainly be returning `false`, indicating that it's failed to parse the string - and it's documented to write `DateTime.MinValue` into the out parameter in that case. You should *definitely* be checking the return value and acting accordingly if parsing is failing.

I *suspect* you want a format string of "yyyy-MM-dd" by the way.

Note that you *shouldn't* be including the date in your SQL string directly in the following line - you should use a parameterized query instead.

Indeed, you shouldn't be converting `x` to a string either - it's already a `DateTime`, so why are you converting it to a string and then parsing it? Your comment indicates that you think a `DateTime` value has a particular format - it doesn't, any more than numbers do - formats relate to how a value is converted into *text*, and isn't inherent in the value itself.

Comment: well thank you so much for the parameterized query thing. i didnt relize the vulnerability earlier. I used to think they are just 2 different styles of writing :(, foolish, i know. i shall edit my question to reflect the changes i have made. Thanks to all of u

Answer (score 1):

Skip all the DateTime to string and back transformation and use **parameters**. You should always use parameters since converting a parameter to string is heavy work and you're prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
DateTime currentDate = InternetTime().Date;

MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
    "SELECT id, dates AS oDates FROM open_dates WHERE dates=?currentDate", connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("?currentDate", MySqlDbTypes.DateTime, currentDate);

da.SelectCommand = cmd;

DataTable dt = new DataTable("openDates");
da.Fill(dt);
```

You can also prepare the SqlCommand/DataAdapter once and change the parameter's value every time you need to:

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters["?currentDate"] = currentDate;
```

Comment: Note that `DateTime currentDate = InternetTime();` should probably be replaced with `DateTime currentDate = InternetTime().Date;`, assuming that the OP is trying to use `ToShortDateString()` to grab the Date part of the `DateTime` object.

Comment: i used your solution and it worked. one thing though it should have been MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
    "SELECT id, dates AS oDates FROM open_dates WHERE dates=?currentDate",connection); Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you doing all these swappings. It would be easier to say:

```
string currentDate = x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); // This gives you the format that you need
```

Second, your format YYYY-MM-DD is not valid. It should be yyyy-MM-dd as specified in ToString().

Third, if you really want to store your date as a string then format it in the SQL statement that you are generating by using

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id,dates AS oDates FROM open_dates     WHERE dates=DATE("+x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+");", con);
```

This way you can ignore all your processing logic defined previously.

Comment: well i didn't know ToString could do that. Thank you so much..you saved my program from a few nonsense lines of code. and the swapping was for test purposes. i had spent a lot of time trying to fix the code and the clean up wasn't done. Some bad coding practices i need to work on, i know :D thanks again